# Rails Activerecord: Map vs pluck vs as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My question is purely based on the performance impact of the 3 approaches. I need to know which is the best method to use for the task at hand.

I need to render json for a specific set of records.

The current approach I use is

```
result = User.all.map{ |u| { name: u.name, id: u.id } }
```

As you may know, this will loop through Activerecord objects and this will have very low performance for a large set of records.

Alternative approach is to use pluck.

```
result = User.all.pluck(:name,:id).map{ |u| { name: u[0], id: u[1] } }
```

Probably much better in performance, but code looks smelly.

The same can be achieved with as_json if we override as_json as include only the necessary parameters but I need to know if this will also iterate through activerecord objects.

Feel free to say if there is any other approach which will give better performance.

Comment: Could you add a database back-end?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use:

```
User.select(:id, :name).to_json
```

It might not be as performant as your `pluck(...).map` version which is indeed very low level. But it is faster than your `all.map` version and more elegant (aka easier to read).

Comment: It's the same as `pluck`.

Comment: @Зелёный No it's not the same. `pluck` returns an array of arrays (therefore you have to map them to return hashes), but `select` returns an array of `ActiveRecord` objects with only the `id` and `name` have been initialized.

Comment: It does the same `select ...` sql query. I can't test for now but I am pretty sure, an array with integers and names like `[[2, "bob"], [3, "bill"]]` uses less low memory than an array with `AR` objects like  `[#<User:0x005579aecdbe00 id: 2, name: "bob">, #<User:0x005579aecdb810 id: 3, name: "bill">]`

Comment: Just for fun [here is a benchmark](https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/d7187210fc08cab6414c). pluck faster more than 3 times.

Comment: so I can't get why is this approach has a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = User.all.as_json(only: [:name, :id])
```